# How to fix "volte_imsvt1 Fail to connect" error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Whenever I connect my phone with Android Studio to run my android app, I get this error in logcat, without even running the app. When I try to run the app it crashes immediately right after launching the app without any notice. How can I fix this?

```
2019-01-29 04:32:34.594 285-737/? E/VT HIDL: [IVT] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] des = volte_imsvt1 Fail to connect . retry count: 61355
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you have fixed your app crashes, but i think to have find a solution to the continuos error in logcat
removing "execute" authorization from vtservice file stored in system/bin
or system/vendor/bin (on my phone); so from octal 0755 to 0644;
resolved the error and saves a lot battery life.

have a nice day!

source
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=755811&st=600